# Star Wars D6 Skills and Advanced Skills

Tags: star-wars-d6

Using 2nd Ed Rev and Exp.

If you do not have a skill can you just use the Attribute dice which govern that skill?

Advanced skills, not much in the book about which (A) skills. Medicine is defined and that's about it. How do they work?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 4):

> If you do not have a skill can you just use the Attribute dice which govern that skill?

Yes. Star Wars does not have an unskilled penalty, and all skills begin at the value of their core attribute.

An attribute of 3D and a skill of 3D are interchangeable.

> Advanced skills, not much in the book about which (A) skills. Medicine is defined and that's about it. How do they work?

Advanced skills are special cases. They're meant to represent things that require a great deal of specialized training and expertise, and the rules can vary from one advanced skill to another.

But most of them follow the template laid out by Medicine:

- Characters who have not explicitly taken the advanced skill may not make checks with it (in contrast to the rules for normal skills above).
- Have a prerequisite skill that a character must have before taking the advanced skill.
- Are improved from 0D, and ignore the base attribute.
- Are more expensive to advance than normal skills (2CP to buy at 1D, double cost to advance from there).
- Provide a bonus to prerequisite skills.

This is spelled out on page 29, 34, and 35.

While only Medicine is listed in the book, you can extrapolate a number of others that are mentioned as examples:

- (A) Space Transports Engineering

  Advanced Skill -- requires *Space Transports Repair* of at least 5D.

  Characters with this skill have the knowledge necessary to design and build new types of Space Transport.
- (A) Starfighter Engineering

  Advanced Skill -- requires *Starfighter Repair* of at least 5D.

  Characters with this skill have the knowledge necessary to design and build new types of Starfighter.
- (A) Droid Engineering

  Advanced Skill -- requires *Droid Programming / Repair* of at least 5D.

  Characters with this skill have the knowledge necessary to design and build new types of Droid.

Comment: @Kilo You're welcome! If this answered your question, please accept it (check-mark shaped button in the upper-left of the question), so that others know your question was answered.